# Perfos : Multiprocessing with shared object between Python 3.5 and 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, performance, python-3.x

I can observe a HUGE time difference between python 2.7 and 3.5 running this piece of code. It seems due to my shared object `_SharedProgress` but i can't figure why python 3.5 (12s to run) is so much slower than 2.7 (1s to run).
Indeed if i comment `progress.update()`, perfos are almost identical (3.5 remains a bit slower).

Can someone explain me why? :)
Of course i would like to keep 2.7 perfo with 3.5...

```
from __future__ import print_function
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from time import time


class _SharedProgress(object):
    current = 0

    def get(self):
        return self.current

    def update(self, new_value=1):
        self.current += new_value


class _GlobalManager(BaseManager):
    BaseManager.register('SharedProgress', _SharedProgress)


class WorkManager:
    def __init__(self, nbWorkers, workerTask):
        self.manager = _GlobalManager()
        self.sharedProgress = None
        self.totalProgress = nbWorkers * 100
        self.pool = []
        start = time()
        self.manager.start()
        self.sharedProgress = self.manager.SharedProgress()
        inputs = [(self.sharedProgress,) for _ in range(nbWorkers)]

        processToLaunch = [i for i in range(nbWorkers)]
        for i in processToLaunch:
            self.pool.append(Process(target=workerTask, args=inputs[i]))
        while processToLaunch or any((w.is_alive() for w in self.pool)):
            if processToLaunch:
                self.pool[processToLaunch.pop(0)].start()
                if self.sharedProgress.get() == self.totalProgress:
                    break
        print("DONE in {}!".format(time() - start))


def __workerTask(progress):
    prevPercent, current, currentPercent, total = 0, 0, 0, 10000
    for i in range(total):
        current += 1
        currentPercent = (current * 100) / total
        if currentPercent != prevPercent:
            progress.update(currentPercent - prevPercent)  # IF I COMMENT THIS LINE, PERFOS ARE ALMOST IDENTICAL
            prevPercent = currentPercent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorkManager(10, __workerTask)
```

Comment: BTW: `processToLaunch = [i for i in range(nbWorkers)]` => `processToLaunch = list(range(nbWorkers))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference comes from the division. In Python 3, dividing two integer values with `/` will always yield a `float`, in Python 2 it remained an `int`. You can force the python2 behavior for both versions by using `//`:

```
currentPercent = (current * 100) // total
```

Or the python3 behavior by initializing `current = 0.`. There still remains some performance gap, which might be caused by the different `int` types in Python 2 and 3. Python 2 used to have separate `int` and `long` types, while Python 3 only has one unified `int` type which covers both. If you force Python 2 to use `long` (`current = 0L`), it becomes even slower than the Python 3 version.

Comment: You're right! By initializing current with 0. and casting currentPercent as int, I keep my functionnal need but perf in python3 are almost the same as python2 (notice that python2 are better with this same new code)

Comment: Don't initialize as `float` (`0.`) and cast. Just use integers throughout and use the integer division `//`. I just mentioned the float-initialization as a way to demonstrate how Python 2 will also be slow if it were using floats - or if you really wanted to make rational number % updates with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes sorry i changed it by "//". I've also noticed a difference when starting my list of processes : in py2, all are launched in almost "one time" whereas in py3, time to launch a new process increase each time!

Comment: @Vince: it may be that your progress bar is slightly overkill if just changing the division type speeds this up that much. You may consider not updating the bar so often.

Comment: @JFF : sure i guess 1% per Process (nominally 10 in //) is a little bit overkill :)
I keep digging concerning "start" phase, as i said i observe in py3 that : "time to start process N" > "time to start process N-1". With huge workload per process (itertools : slicing on massive product), first processes start witin 1s interval whereas process 6 and more take easely more than 10-20s to start. It was not the case in py2. I try to generate "light scenario" for SO :)

Comment: @Zulan: I just realized that floating point division just triggered a side effect: the progress bar is _always_ updated because floating point values change (`if currentPercent != prevPercent` is always `True`), whereas when it's integers, they don't change until some threshold is reached. So yes, integer division is the key, but not by itself. overfrequent progress bar redraw is the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

As Zulan noted,

```
currentPercent = (current * 100) // total
```

fixes the issue, but the performance issue is not directly related to integer or floating point division.

When performing a floating point division, `currentPercent` is *always* different from `prevPercent`, so progress bar is updated at every iteration, which is considerable redraw work, whereas with integer division, it's just updated 100 times.

This overfrequent redraw is the actual cause of the slowdowns.

Comment: I thought that was obvious, but I guess it wasn't quite. Thanks for the clarification.